# Cannot iterate over iterator with array_walk since php 7.4

Tags: php, iterator, array-walk

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator([1, 2]);
array_walk($iterator, function($item) {echo $item . PHP_EOL;});
```

This piece of php code outputs the items (1 and 2) in php 7.3 but it outputs nothing in php 7.4. Can anyone explain what changed in php 7.4 that resulted in this change ? I cannot find anything related to that in the changelogs.

Comment: I've tried that, you're right. When you use array without ArrayIterator it works. There's no deprecation note inside the docs.

Comment: Just to narrow down a bit further. 7.3.19 works, 7.4.0 doesn't. There was a change to the ArrayItterator (#78409) in 7.4.0. Ref: https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php

Comment: I see a deprecation for `ArrayObject` but not for this .See the [reference](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/PHP-7.4/UPGRADING), search for SPL section

Comment: With a bit of bisecting, the culprit is https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a5fa51afbbd87bedeb1c5fd7c9a6cf3c971ab14c#diff-a84ed8c7e86da360bb911990cf291d04

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs to work around this, you can convert iterator to array.

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator([1, 2]);
$array = iterator_to_array($iterator);
array_walk($array, function($item) {echo $item . PHP_EOL;});
```

https://3v4l.org/Xq9Dc

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit deprecation of this feature (ie `array_walk()` used on instances of `ArrayIterator`) however after further investigation I have found that as of PHP7.4, `array_walk()` will work on the properties of the `ArrayIterator` and not it's encapsulated array. Although this case is not explicitly stated in the manual, I'm sure this is the reason.

To summarise the manual (Migrating to PHP7.4 > Backward Incompatible Changes > Standard PHP Library (SPL))

Calling `get_object_vars()` on `ArrayObject` (and `ArrayIterator`) returns the properties of the instance, where pre php7.4 it returned the wrapped array. Potentially affected operations are those working on object properties as a list eg `array_walk()`.

so what you're getting is the `ArrayIterator` instances property list, which is empty because the array is stored in a private property.

[Incompatible Changes to PHP7.4 - php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.spl)

> Standard PHP Library (SPL)
>
> Calling `get_object_vars()` on an `ArrayObject` instance will now always return the properties of the `ArrayObject` itself (or a subclass). Previously it returned the values of the wrapped array/object unless the `ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST` flag was specified.
>
> Other affected operations are:
>
> - `ReflectionObject::getProperties()`
> - `reset()`, `current()`, etc. Use `Iterator` methods instead.
> - Potentially others working on object properties as a list, e.g. `array_walk()`.
>
> `(array)` casts are not affected. They will continue to return either the wrapped array, or the `ArrayObject` properties, depending on whether the `ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST` flag is used.